# Oozie Workflow : How to get current action node name?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

How to get the `name` of current `action` in oozie workflow?

Eg :

```
<action name="hello_action">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>/user/nz/printActionName.sh</exec>
        <argument><!-- PASS current action name i.e. hello_action  --></argument>
        <file>/user/nz/printActionName.sh#printActionName.sh</file>
        <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Comment: Action name is static, right? Just pass it as string

Comment: Yes, I can do `<argument>hello_action</argument>` but actually I'm having more than 100 such actions, and to avoid copy-paste errors, was wondering if there is an easier way

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way in Oozie to get the current action node name. However, the workaround would be:

1. Get workflowId using EL function;
2. Query the workflow status using Oozie API;
3. Get the name of the ID that is running;
4. Split by '@'.,which is your step name

Answer (score 0):

When Oozie submits the Shell Action to YARN, it ships a XML file with some information about the current Workflow and Action, and sets an env. variable to point to that file. Just parse the XML with **sed** and *voila*.

```
if [[ "$CONTAINER_ID" != "" && "$OOZIE_ACTION_CONF_XML" != "" ]]
then
  RawDump=$(/bin/sed -n '/<name>mapreduce.job.name<\/name>/ { N ; s/^.*<value>oozie:action:/:/ ; s/<\/value>.*$/:/ ; p}' "$OOZIE_ACTION_CONF_XML")
  MyOozieWorkflow=$(/bin/echo "$RawDump" | /bin/sed -n '/:W=[^:]*:/ { s/^.*W=// ; s/:.*$// ; p }')
  MyOozieJobId=$(   /bin/echo "$RawDump" | /bin/sed -n '/:ID=[^:]*:/ { s/^.*ID=// ; s/:.*$// ; p }')
  MyOozieAction=$(  /bin/echo "$RawDump" | /bin/sed -n '/:A=[^:]*:/ { s/^.*A=// ; s/:.*$// ; p }')
else
  MyOozieWorkflow='None'
  MyOozieJobId='None'
  MyOozieAction='None'
fi
```